# How to put results of two queries in same table

Tags: mysql, select

In MySQL I have two tables with many transactions. I'm using two SELECT queries two find the results as noted below, but i can't find a way to put them together as in the end of the post. Below are the details of the queries and the result of them:

Query 1:

```
SELECT SUM( o.paid ) AS Income, DATE( FROM_UNIXTIME( o.time ) ) AS DATE
FROM  `orders_successful` AS o
WHERE DATE( FROM_UNIXTIME( o.time ) ) < CURDATE( ) 
AND o.type <>8
GROUP BY DATE( FROM_UNIXTIME( o.time ) ) 
ORDER BY o.time DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT SUM( t.amount ) AS Commissions, DATE( t.datetime ) AS DATE
FROM  `tb_user_txns` AS t
WHERE DATE( t.datetime ) < CURDATE( ) 
GROUP BY DATE( t.datetime ) 
ORDER BY t.datetime DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

Result of Query 1:

```
+--------+------------+
| Income |    Date    |
+--------+------------+
| 4,667  | 13-01-2015 |
| 4,118  | 12-01-2015 |
| 3,427  | 11-01-2015 |
| 3,484  | 10-01-2015 |
| 3,711  | 09-01-2015 |
+--------+------------+
```

Result of Query 2:

```
+-------------+------------+
| Commissions |    Date    |
+-------------+------------+
|         350 | 13-01-2015 |
|         300 | 12-01-2015 |
|         225 | 11-01-2015 |
|         211 | 10-01-2015 |
|         262 | 09-01-2015 |
+-------------+------------+
```

Ok, what i would like to do is an output like this:

```
+--------+-------------+------------+
| Income | Commissions |    Date    |
+--------+-------------+------------+
| 4,667  |         350 | 13-01-2015 |
| 4,118  |         300 | 12-01-2015 |
| 3,427  |         225 | 11-01-2015 |
| 3,484  |         211 | 10-01-2015 |
| 3,711  |         262 | 09-01-2015 |
+--------+-------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have your queries as subqueries and then do join

you can change join to `left join` to get all results from one query in case dates doesn't exists in another.

```
select t1.Income,
       t2.Comissions,
       t1.Date
from ( first query here ) t1
join ( second query here ) t2
on t1.date = t2.date
```

Comment: It works great!!! I cannot give you some points because i have not enough reputation. Btw thanks a lot!